# What's the best way to remove strings?

Tags: c#, .net, string, performance

I need ideas  with the best performance to remove/filter strings

I have:

```
string Input = "view('512', 3, 159);";
```

What's the best performance way to remove "view(" and ");" and the quotes? 
I can do this:

```
Input = Input.Replace("view(","").Replace("'","").Replace("\"","").Replace(");","");
```

but it seems rather inelegant.

```
Input.Split('(')[1].Split(')')[0].Replace("'", "");
```

it seems rather better

I want no do it by using regular expression; I need make the faster application what I can.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: There's got to be some linq in here somewhere

Comment: Why do you not want to use regular expressions?

Comment: You're saying `best` as in `best performance`, right?

Comment: Regex is possibly faster in this case...  Do you need to deal with nested parentheses?

Comment: @Freed:to best performance @Frédéric Hamidi:yes,response updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a simple linq statement:

```
string Input = "view('512', 3, 159);";

string output = new String( Input.Where( c => Char.IsDigit( c ) || c == ',' ).ToArray() );
```

Output: 512,3,159

If you want the spaces, just add a check in the where clause.

Answer (score 2):

You could use just a `Substring` to remove the `view(` and `);`:

```
Input.Substring(5, Input.Length - 7)
```

Other than that it looks reasonably efficient. Plain string operations are pretty well optimised.

So:

```
Input =
  Input.Substring(5, Input.Length - 7)
  .Replace("'", String.Empty)
  .Replace("\"", String.Enmpty);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char[] Output = Input.SkipWhile(x => x != '(') // skip before open paren
                     .Skip(1)                  // skip open paren
                     .TakeWhile(x => x != ')') // take everything until close paren
                     .Where(x => x != '\'' && x != '\"') // except quotes
                     .ToArray();
return new String(Output);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps

```
Regex.Replace("view('512', 3, 159);",@"[(view)';]","")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb=new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        int state=0;
        for(var i=0;i<Input.Length;i++){
            switch(state){
                case 0: // beginning
                    if(Input[i]=='('){
                        state=1; // seen left parenthesis
                    }
                    break;
                case 2: // seen end parentheses
                    break; // ignore
                case 1:
                    if(Input[i]==')'){
                        state=2; // seen right parentheses
                    } else if(Input[i]!='\''){

                        sb.Append(Input[i]);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Trouble is this might well be quickest (worth checking anyway)

Comment: I will reinstate the regular expression if it does turn out to be faster, though I believe it wouldn't make much difference.

Comment: As it turns out, the regular expression that was previously here was more than twice as slow, after running each approach 200,000 times.

Answer (score 1):

IndexOf, LastIndexOf, and Substring are probably fastest.

```
string Input = "view('512', 3, 159);"; 
int p1 = Input.IndexOf('(');
int p2 = Input.LastIndexOf(')');
Input = Input.Substring (p1 + 1, p2 - p1 - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var result = new string(Input.ToCharArray().
SkipWhile (i => i != '\'').
TakeWhile (i => i != ')').ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to use regular expressions? Regular expressions are heavily optimised and will be much faster than any hand written hack.

This is java (as I run linux and can't run c# as a result), but I hope you get the idea.

```
input.replace("view(","").replace("'","").replace("\"","").replace(");","");
```

A million repetitions of the above runs in about 6 seconds on my computer. Whereas, the regular expression below runs in about 2 seconds.

```
// create java's regex matcher object
// matcher is looking for sequences of digits (valid integers)
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)").matcher(s);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
// whilst we can find matches append the match plus a comma to a string builder
while (matcher.find()) {
    builder.append(matcher.group()).append(',');
}
// return the built string less the last trailing comma
return builder.substring(0, builder.length()-1);
```

If you want to find valid decimals as well as integers then use the following pattern instead. Though it runs slightly slower than the original.

```
"(\\d+(\\.\\d*)?)"
```

Comment: I know you said you didn't want to use regular expressions, but I think you're making a mistake. After the initial learning curve writing a good regex is faster, clearer and cleaner than a hand written alternative, but it will also perform faster than the functional and imperative answers here.

Answer (score 0):

fastest way would be `Input = Input.Substring(5, Input.Length - 7)`

Comment: This won't get rid of the quote after 512.

Comment: I assume the question is how to extract part of a string in quotes, not how to extract that specific range in the specific example?

Comment: @Femaref, or of the one before `512` either.

Comment: That will cause an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. You can't get characters beyond the end of the string.

Comment: @Guffa: fixed, I forgot the 2nd param is length and not endPos

Answer (score 0):

More generic

```
void Main()
{
    string Input = "view('512', 3, 159);";
    var statingPoint = Input.IndexOf('(') + 1;

    var result = Input.Substring(statingPoint, Input.IndexOf(')') - statingPoint);
}
```