# how to replace multiple chars from a string?

Tags: c#

what is the equivalent of below:

```
contact.name.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "");
```

Thanks

Comment: check: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657278/whats-the-best-way-to-remove-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular Expression [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx) should do the trick

```
contact.name = Regex.Replace(contact.name, @"[\(\)\- ]", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ:

```
var s = "abcd 238(23)2342-23";
var exclusion = "()- ";

var result = new string(s.ToCharArray().Where (x => !exclusion.Contains(x)).ToArray());
```

or

```
var s = "abcd 238(23)2342-23";

var result = new string(s.ToCharArray().Where (x => !"()- ".Contains(x)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder will be more effecient if you're doing more than a few replacements.